# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java

Tags: java, apache, maven

I'm trying to execute a Maven proyect, but when I do I get this msg:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
```

This is my Mojo plugin dependency:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>HiveClient</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

I don't know if I need more properties or so, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?